# How to use custom dylib in library project in xcode 4?

Tags: c, xcode, shared-libraries, dylib

I'm writing a shared library (dylib) in c using xcode 4.2 say X.dylib. In this project I need to use other very specific dylib, say Y.dylib. I want to keep it in the project and ship together.

Right now compilation of X.dylib fails unless I put Y.dylib in /usr/local/lib. But I want to have it in my local bundle/project.

How to configure xcode in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.6 you just need to drag your framework onto your Xcode project, and check `Copy items into destinations groups's folder` and check all targets you want to add the library to.